# What kind of data preprocessing is required before running a clustering algorithm?

Tags: clustering, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

I have a dataset that consists of 87 observations or rows of data. My variables are a mix of different kinds - continuous, categorical and some count. Examples are variables which are percentage types, variables whose values are numbers and some counts.

My objective is to find natural groupings among the 87 observations. I have been tasked to choose one method among k-means, k-medians or hierarchical types.

I have tried doing the following:

1. Started with hierarchical clustering. Used only the continuous variables in the dataset to try and get clusters; but that did not work as I keep/kept getting the following error: "Invalid (dis)similarity option".
2. Tried standardizing the variables since they are on different scales and then running hierarchical clustering. Still the same error as above.
3. I have used linkage methods like wardslinkage, centroidlinkage, medianlinkage etc... but I am getting the same error

I am of the opinion that variables which have values as whole numbers or percentages are continuous variables. But, please let me know if I might be wrong?

There is clear guidance available in literature as to what linkage method is appropriate when certain kinds of variables are present. However, for some reason, none of my linkage methods within hierarchical clustering seem to be running properly.

Comment: What dissimilarity measure are you using?

Comment: I have been trying to use all possible dissimilarity measures - L2, L2squared, L1, and Linfinity. However, none of them seem to work. Since these are the recommended dissimilarity measures when working with continuous variables, I am trying to use one or the other among them. But I am getting the following error - invalid dissimilarity option. Not sure why???

Answer (score 1):

"Invalid (dis)similarity option"

is not an error caused by preprocessing, but a programming error in your code (which is why it does not go away if you change your data)

Could even be a typo.

Comment: Thanks. After rechecking my code, I did figure out that I had an error in the syntax in my code. I have now been able to fix this error and am able to proceed. 
However, as an aside, I would like to mention for the benefit of everyone, that sometimes it is beneficial to first do a factor analysis to reduce the number of variables into a smaller number of factors and possibly use those as the bases of segmentation or variables for clustering.
Besides, factor analysis could also help in putting all variables differently scaled into a common standardized scale and then use them in the clustering